# UK garden flower identification

Tags: identification, flowers

I planted a random collection of old unlabeled seeds. Most of what sprouted i recognised but what is this plant? The flower is about an inch across.  The leaves and stems are very delicate. It also sprouted in a pale orange colour and a blueish colour

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common name is flowering flax, scientific name: *Linum grandiflorum*. It's an annual, and not native to the UK (but originates from North Africa). It can be found in British gardens, though, see Gardener's world [webpage](https://www.gardenersworld.com/plants/linum-grandiflorum/).